# compare buffers as fast as possible

Tags: c, windows, sse

I need to compare two buffers chunk-wise for equality. I don't need information about the relation of the two buffers, just if each two chunks are equal or not. My intel machine supports up to SSE4.2

The naive approach is:

```
const size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 16; //128bit for SSE2 integer registers
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 200000000;

char* array_1 = (char*)_aligned_malloc(ARRAY_SIZE, 16);
char* array_2 = (char*)_aligned_malloc(ARRAY_SIZE, 16);

for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; )
{
    volatile bool result = memcmp(array_1+i, array_2+i, CHUNK_SIZE);
    i += CHUNK_SIZE;
}
```

Compared to my first try using SSE ever:

```
union U
{
    __m128i m;
    volatile int i[4];
} res;

for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; )
{
    __m128i* pa1 = (__m128i*)(array_1+i);
    __m128i* pa2 = (__m128i*)(array_2+i);
    res.m = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(*pa1, *pa2);
    volatile bool result =  ( (res.i[0]==0) || (res.i[1]==0) || (res.i[2]==0) || (res.i[3]==0) );
    i += CHUNK_SIZE;
}
```

The gain in speed is about 33%. Could I do any better?

Comment: do you have a bottleneck in this particular code?

Comment: Yes, it's the main hot spot in my program.

Comment: Unless your `memcmpy` implementation is broken you'll have a hard time beating it - it should already be SIMD-optimised.

Comment: But I still measure a gain. I'm using VS2005 and diving into the release mode compiled memcmp function does not bring up any SSE opcode.

Comment: I also want to mention that the question is general, so if there is any other approach beside memcmp or SSE I'm very interested in it.

Comment: OK - with a decent compiler/libraries/OS you should see no improvement over memcmp - if your solution is going to be portable and optimal then you probably want to #ifdef it for WIN32 and use memcmp for anything other than WIN32.

Comment: Added "windows" tag, since you are comparing with MSVC version of memcmp.

Comment: Are we surprised that a model 2005 compiler isn't using SSE4 instructions?

Comment: Do we know anything specific about the data? Are some positions more likely to differ than others? A better algorithm is worth a thousand optimizations.

Comment: @Bo: I tried the VC10 Compiler now. No SSE instructions inside memcpy as well.

Comment: The data can unfortunately be anything.

Comment: Oh and the funny thing is: The VS2010 compiler output is slower on my machine than the VS2005 output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using scalar code and unions to test all the individual vector elements - do something like this instead:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i += CHUNK_SIZE)
{
    const __m128i a1 = _mm_load_si128(array_1 + i);
    const __m128i a2 = _mm_load_si128(array_2 + i);
    const __m128i vcmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(a1, a2);
    const int vmask = _mm_movemask_epi8(vcmp);
    const bool result = (vmask == 0xffff);
    // you probably want to break here if you get a mismatch ???
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the kind if information that I'm looking for

Comment: But unfortunately the gain is the same compared to using the union for this special case.

Comment: It may well be that your bottleneck is memory bandwidth, so speeding up the comparison operations could be fruitless.

Comment: Is there any easy way to prove that for my setup?

Comment: You can just do the math and see how many MB/sec you're comparing, then compare that with your FSB bandwidth.

Comment: To decrease the complexity when the two numbers are different you can break the loop in that case. To do so change the first line with: `bool result=false;  for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE && !result; i += CHUNK_SIZE)` and remove the `const bool` in the last line inside the loop. If you want to make your code more understandable you may change the name `result` with `areequal`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can use SSE 4.1, there is another alternative that might be faster:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i += CHUNK_SIZE;)
{
    __m128i* pa1 = (__m128i*)(array_1+i);
    __m128i* pa2 = (__m128i*)(array_2+i);
    __m128i temp = _mm_xor_si128(*pa1, *pa2);
    bool result = (bool)_mm_testz_si128(temp, temp);
}
```

`_mm_testz_si128(a, b)` returns `0` if `a & b != 0` and it returns `1` if `a & b == 0`. The advantage is that you can use this version with the new AVX instructions as well, where the chunk size is 32 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately VS2005 doesn't support SSE above v2 as I learned in that moment. Maybe I can find out the opcodes and use inline asm instead.

Comment: I tried using the intel compiler supporting this instrincts. The performance is comparable to both other approaches presented here.

Comment: Thanks for trying the code out. It is quite likely that memory bandwidth is the bottleneck here, as noted by Paul R. This code could be potentially 1 or 2 cycles faster.